# How can I associate NetSuite TRANSACTION_LINES with REVENUE_RECOGNITION_SCHEDULES via ODBC?

Tags: netsuite

How can I associate NetSuite `TRANSACTION_LINES` with `REVENUE_RECOGNITION_SCHEDULES` via ODBC?

I have researched the Connect Schema. While it says that it should be possible to join `REVENUE_RECOGNITION_SCHEDULES.JOURNAL_ID` TO `TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_ID`, it breaks down if I try to look for individual invoices.

Comment: commenting to save for reference later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TRANSACTION_LINES view has a column called SCHEDULE_ID which matches the corresponding SCHEDULE_ID in the REVRECSCHEDULES view.

```
SELECT 
    T.TRANID
    ,R.SCHEDULE_ID
FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
INNER JOIN 
    TRANSACTION_LINES AS TL
    ON T.TRANSACTION_ID = TL.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN 
    REVRECSCHEDULES AS R
    ON TL.SCHEDULE_ID = R.SCHEDULE_ID
WHERE
    T.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'Invoice'
    AND T.TRANID = 'R0356788'
```

Comment: I did not find this in the documentation and it is vital to calculating revenue. Thank you Mike.